# ASP.NET Core 6 - Cookie gets returned but not stored in browser

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, fetch, asp.net-core-identity

I am struggling with Cookie Authentication in Asp.Net Core 6.0

I have implemented and configured the Cookie Authentication and the problem I am facing is the following.

When sending POST request to the login Endpoint which is at `<domain>/api/account/login` the login returns a 200 OK response and the correct cookie.

However, the Cookie is not getting stored in the browser.

**The Cookie Configurations**

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
      options.Cookie.Name = "Affito.Identity";
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
      options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
      options.Cookie.SameSite = (SameSiteMode) (-1);
      options.SlidingExpiration = true;
      options.Cookie.Domain = ".affito.ch";
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
      options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

  services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = (SameSiteMode)(-1);
    options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
  });
```

since I have multiple subdomains that need to work with the same cookie I have the .domain attribute in options.Cookie.Domain.

This is the response from the Network Tab in the browser after sending the login request
[image]

However, the Cookie is getting returned but it is not getting stored in the browser for future requests.

I am sending a simple fetch request from the React-App:

```
const response = await fetch(BASEURL + "/account/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

console.log(response);
```

};

Am I missing something or why does it not store the cookie in the browser.
I have consulted the docs but could not figure that out.

**Swagger:**
When sending the request from swagger, it returns the same cookie and stores it correctly in the browser.
[image]

I guessed it had something to do with the 'SameSite' Restriction that's why I took it out but it still does not work when sending the request from **stage."domain"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to add the correct CORS policy. If you expect a Cookie to be stored and included in future requests, you must add the Origins and the .WithCredentials() properties to the Cors policy.

**It might look something like this:**

```
service.AddCors(options =>
    {
      options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", builder =>
      {
        builder
          .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://example.com")
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowCredentials();
      });
    });
```